# Why could my code to access the FPL API using https://github.com/amosbastian/fpl be failing?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to access the FPL API via the following package "https://github.com/amosbastian/fpl" in Python 3.7.6 (Jupyter Notebook). The quickstart guide has a very simple piece of code that just does nothing when I run it. Can't work out why just copying and pasting the guide code doesn't work:

```
from fpl import FPL
import aiohttp

async def main():
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    fpl = FPL(session)
    player = await fpl.get_player(302)
    print(player)
    await session.close()
```

Any ideas why this might just do nothing?

P.S. Sorry if this is really basic - I'm pretty new to Python

Answer (score 0):

Mainly because no code should run.

This code just imports some packages and defines one function - nothing calls it. If you are this new to Python and programming I'd recommend one of beginner Python tutorials that explain concepts.